# Update the Html Table Data without using database in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I Have a Html table .What i am trying to do is without using database.Perform the crud operation.I am able to doing adding the data to html table and deleting the data fine.But i am not able to the update operation.When I click on the edit button on the html table getting data.How to assign That data into textboxes and do the update based on index.Is there any way to do it.Please Anybody Help.Thanks in Advance.

### Jquery code for adding and deleting the row

```js
 

   $(function() {
        $('.plusdiv #adddata').on('click', function() {

            var orgname, from, todate, capacity, orgid;
            orgid = $("#orgid").val();
            orgname = $("#orgname").val();
            from = $("#fromdt").val();
            todate = $("#todt").val();
            capacity = $("#cpcty").val();

           
            
            var edit = "<a class='editedu' href='#'><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></i></a>";
            var del = "<a class='deleteedu' href='#'><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a>";

            if (orgname == "" || from == "" || todate == "") {
                alert("Fields should not be empty");
            } else {
                var table = "<tr><td>" + orgname + "</td><td>" + from + "</td><td>" + todate + "</td><td>" + capacity + "</td><td>" + edit + "</td><td>" + del + "</td></tr>";
                $("#tableexp").append(table);
            }
            orgid = $("#orgid").val("");
            orgname = $("#orgname").val("");
            from = $("#fromdt").val("");
            todate = $("#todt").val("");
            capacity = $("#cpcty").val("");
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $("#tableexp").on("click", ".deleteedu", function(e) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete")) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $('.crossdiv #cleardata').on('click', function() {
            $("#orgid").val("");
            $("#orgname").val("");
            $("#fromdt").val("");
            $("#todt").val("");
            $("#cpcty").val("");
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        var  row, td;
        $("#tableexp").on("click", ".editedu", function(e) {
            row = $(this).closest('tr');
            td = row.find("td");
            $.each(td, function() {
   //i am getting the td data how to assign data to textboxes and do update
                console.log($(this).html());
            });
           

        });
    });
```

```css
CSS code For Table
---------------------------
   

 #tableexp th,td{
            text-align:center;
            font-size:17px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
         }

    #tableexp{
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    #tableexp th{
    font-size: 17px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    }

    #tableexp tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #dddddd;
    }


HTML Code
-----------------------------
```

```html
 

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <div id="a8" style="float:left;width:100%;margin:5px 0px 10px 10px;text-align:left;font-size:17px;">
        <div class="yopdiv" style="float:left;width:10.5%;font-size:16px;margin-top:3px;font-family:arial;">
            <label>Organisation</label>
        </div>
        <div class="org" style="float:left;width:24%;">
            <input style="display:none;" id="orgid" type="text" name="orgid" value="1" />
            <input type="text" name="organisation" id="orgname" style="width:95%;height:20px;font-size:17px;" value="" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="formlbl" style="float:left;width:5.5%;font-size:16px;margin-top:3px;font-family:arial;">
            <label>From </label>
        </div>
        <div class="formtxt" style="float:left;width:10%;">
            <input type="text" id="fromdt" name="fromdate" maxlength="10" style="width:95%;height:20px;font-size:15px;" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="tolbl" style="float:left;width:4%;font-size:16px;margin:3px 0px 0 15px;font-family:arial;">
            <label>To</label>
        </div>
        <div class="totxt" style="float:left;width:10%;font-size:18px;">
            <input type="text" name="todate" id="todt" value="" style="width:90%;height:20px;font-size:17px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="cpctylbl" style="float:left;width:6%;font-size:16px;margin:3px 0px 0 15px;font-family:arial;">
            <label>Capacity</label>
        </div>
        <div class="cptxt" style="float:left;width:16%;font-size:18px;">
            <input type="text" name="capacity" id="cpcty" value="" style="width:97%;height:20px;font-size:17px;" />
        </div>

        <div class="plusdiv" style="float:left;width:3%;margin-left:-2px;padding-left:20px;">
            <a id='adddata' href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="width:70%;font-size:25px;color:white;background-color:#dc143c;padding-left:2px;"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="crossdiv" style="float:left;width:5%;padding-left:10px;">
            <a id='cleardata' href="#"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="width:50%;font-size:25px;color:white;background-color:#dc143c;padding-left:4px;"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="exptable" class="expdiv" style="max-height:140px;overflow: auto; width:100%;">
        <table cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" id=tableexp>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:25%;">Organisation</th>
                    <th style="width:20%;">From</th>
                    <th style="width:13%;">To</th>
                    <th style="width:20%;">Capacity</th>
                    <th style="width:5%;">Edit</th>
                    <th style="width:5%;">Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use a js array to store your table row's data. Add, edit and delete from the js array and after each operation just refresh the html table based on that js array

Comment: Another approach - just to make td editable like this: <td><div contenteditable>I'm editable</div></td>

Comment: Hope, you want **[to achieve this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/wenbsjpc/6/)**.

Comment: **[How about this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/wenbsjpc/25/)**? This is just a rough one. Still you can refine the code..

Comment: Ok Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign them directly, using the html() method...

```js
$(function() {
        $('.plusdiv #adddata').on('click', function() {

            var orgname, from, todate, capacity, orgid;
            orgid = $("#orgid").val();
            orgname = $("#orgname").val();
            from = $("#fromdt").val();
            todate = $("#todt").val();
            capacity = $("#cpcty").val();

           
            
            var edit = "<a class='editedu' href='#'><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></i></a>";
            var del = "<a class='deleteedu' href='#'><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a>";

            if (orgname == "" || from == "" || todate == "") {
                alert("Fields should not be empty");
            } else {
                var table = "<tr><td>" + orgname + "</td><td>" + from + "</td><td>" + todate + "</td><td>" + capacity + "</td><td>" + edit + "</td><td>" + del + "</td></tr>";
                $("#tableexp").append(table);
            }
            orgid = $("#orgid").val("");
            orgname = $("#orgname").val("");
            from = $("#fromdt").val("");
            todate = $("#todt").val("");
            capacity = $("#cpcty").val("");
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $("#tableexp").on("click", ".deleteedu", function(e) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete")) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $('.crossdiv #cleardata').on('click', function() {
            $("#orgid").val("");
            $("#orgname").val("");
            $("#fromdt").val("");
            $("#todt").val("");
            $("#cpcty").val("");
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        var  row, td;
        $("#tableexp").on("click", ".editedu", function(e) {
            row = $(this).closest('tr');
            td = row.find("td");
            $('#orgname').val($(td[0]).html());
            $('#fromdt').val($(td[1]).html());
            $('#todt').val($(td[2]).html());
            $('#cpcty').val($(td[3]).html());
            
            //$.each(td, function() {
   //i am getting the td data how to assign data to textboxes and do update
               // console.log($(this).html());
               // $('#orgname')
            //});
           

        });
    });
```

```css
CSS code For Table
---------------------------
   

 #tableexp th,td{
            text-align:center;
            font-size:17px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
         }

    #tableexp{
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    #tableexp th{
    font-size: 17px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    }

    #tableexp tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #dddddd;
    }


HTML Code
-----------------------------
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <div id="a8" style="float:left;width:100%;margin:5px 0px 10px 10px;text-align:left;font-size:17px;">
        <div class="yopdiv" style="float:left;width:10.5%;font-size:16px;margin-top:3px;font-family:arial;">
            <label>Organisation</label>
        </div>
        <div class="org" style="float:left;width:24%;">
            <input style="display:none;" id="orgid" type="text" name="orgid" value="1" />
            <input type="text" name="organisation" id="orgname" style="width:95%;height:20px;font-size:17px;" value="" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="formlbl" style="float:left;width:5.5%;font-size:16px;margin-top:3px;font-family:arial;">
            <label>From </label>
        </div>
        <div class="formtxt" style="float:left;width:10%;">
            <input type="text" id="fromdt" name="fromdate" maxlength="10" style="width:95%;height:20px;font-size:15px;" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="tolbl" style="float:left;width:4%;font-size:16px;margin:3px 0px 0 15px;font-family:arial;">
            <label>To</label>
        </div>
        <div class="totxt" style="float:left;width:10%;font-size:18px;">
            <input type="text" name="todate" id="todt" value="" style="width:90%;height:20px;font-size:17px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="cpctylbl" style="float:left;width:6%;font-size:16px;margin:3px 0px 0 15px;font-family:arial;">
            <label>Capacity</label>
        </div>
        <div class="cptxt" style="float:left;width:16%;font-size:18px;">
            <input type="text" name="capacity" id="cpcty" value="" style="width:97%;height:20px;font-size:17px;" />
        </div>

        <div class="plusdiv" style="float:left;width:3%;margin-left:-2px;padding-left:20px;">
            <a id='adddata' href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="width:70%;font-size:25px;color:white;background-color:#dc143c;padding-left:2px;"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="crossdiv" style="float:left;width:5%;padding-left:10px;">
            <a id='cleardata' href="#"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="width:50%;font-size:25px;color:white;background-color:#dc143c;padding-left:4px;"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="exptable" class="expdiv" style="max-height:140px;overflow: auto; width:100%;">
        <table cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" id=tableexp>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:25%;">Organisation</th>
                    <th style="width:20%;">From</th>
                    <th style="width:13%;">To</th>
                    <th style="width:20%;">Capacity</th>
                    <th style="width:5%;">Edit</th>
                    <th style="width:5%;">Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: it is working fine.but how to remove the old one and append the latest update row to table.Thanks in Advance.